# Phantom Material: why formaldehyde doesn't rise my jelly melting point?

Tags: solutions, melting-point

Just to be clear, I'm not a chemical but only a electronic engineer which want create a "phantom material" to reproduce the electrical characteristic of epidermis for the analysis of electrodes impedance.

I found [this](https://digi.lib.ttu.ee/i/?3396) paper which explain very well the process to create the phantom. As described, the use of formaldehyde is very useful to rise up the melting point of jelly to menage the final product even at room temperature. The quantity I need to fill my container is 285 ml so I scaled the doses in Table 3 at pg. 31 in the paper. I got

- **285 ml** distilled water
- **8.55 g** of gelatine foil (in the paper is used the powder but I found only the foils. The product says 12, or 20 g, foils for 1 litre of water but I rised this dose to get a more solid jelly)
- **0.96 ml** of formaldehyde (37%)
- **0 g** of NaCl (I need the lower conductive type)
- **0 g** of ethyl 4-hydroxybenzoate (I haven't found this product)

I dissolved the gelatine foils in hot distilled water, then added the formaldehyde and, after the temperature of mixture has dropped, putted all in the fridge.

Now the problem is that the my phantom melts even at room temperature. It seems the formaldehyde doesn't his job.

Did I do something wrong?